# Need help with Ranger Rick sci-fi story

Tags: story-identification

A very long time ago, I saw a sci-fi story on a "Ranger Rick" magazine about a space explorer girl that arrives to a planet that has become a landfill (no spoilers here: it's Earth) and needs the help from a local alien to find spare parts for her ship.

I would appreciate the title and issue number.

Comment: How long ago is "a very long time"?

Comment: I was in school.

Comment: I've struggled to find a good cover shot. If you do end up purchasing it, can you add a pic?

Comment: Will do, man. No prob.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10151090357297003.442394.7393887002&type=3 Think it can be found here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **Ranger Rick Magazine - September, 1990 (Volume 24, #9)**

[The Gazette](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1957&dat=19901122&id=NXYhAAAAIBAJ&sjid=O4kFAAAAIBAJ&pg=1272,6493365) offers the following review:

> "There's a short story about a girl space explorer who lands on a
>   planet that has been poisoned by mountains of garbage. The mutant
>   creatures who live in the slimy, smelly caverns have the methane gas
>   she needs to refuel her space pod. Of course, the planet turns out to
>   be the one her ancestors abandoned years before - Earth"

Comment: Purchasable from all good booksellers; http://www.abebooks.co.uk/servlet/SearchResults?an=&tn=Ranger%20Rick%20September%201990&cm_sp=mbc-_-ats-_-all

Comment: I remember that one.